# Merge mod-pagespeed and page-speed or change tooltip

Tags: discussion, tags, merge

There are different tags for [mod-pagespeed](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mod-pagespeed) and [page-speed](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/page-speed), but these seem largely the same tag. They should be synonymed.

this is the tootip infos

- mod-pagespeed

> PageSpeed Module speeds up your site and reduces page load time. This
>   open-source webserver module automatically applies web performance
>   best practices to pages and associated assets (CSS, JavaScript,
>   images) without requiring that you modify your existing content or
>   workflow.

- page-speed

> PageSpeed is a WebServer module that automatically optimizes pages and
>   the resources they use. Google offers it as a free service through
>   their DNS product.

Answer (score 1):

No, they shouldn't. `mod_pagespeed` concerns [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/), while `page-speed` is a  much more generic term (see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/736126) question as an example).

Those tags are not optimal, but they are not synonyms.

Comment: That s what i get on the tooltip : http://serverfault.com/tags/page-speed/info